# NodeJS express-handlebars operator helpers?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, express-handlebars

I have been using [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/), which allows me to make helpers like this:

```
const Handlebars = require('handlebars');

Handlebars.registerHelper('gt', function( a, b ){
    var next =  arguments[arguments.length-1];
    return (a > b) ? next.fn(this) : next.inverse(this);
})
```

How can I do this with express-handlebars?

Comment: Did you check [the README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars#user-content-helpers)?

Comment: The readme seems to be blank for me?

Comment: It loads fine on the NPM site for me, and is also going to be in your `node_modules/`.

Comment: Did you click on the link provided by jonrsharpe? Is the NPM website blocked to you for some reason? If NPM is blocked due to corporate policies (which is weird because you're doing javascript development) try reading the README doc on the link using another PC/laptop or your Android/iPhone.